# vbs Outlook Signature, different result on 2013 compared to 2010/2016 - Selection.GoTo?

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, ms-word

I found this script that uses a Word template and placeholders to generate an Outlook signature and set the generated signature in Outlook. - Link removed due to not having more than 10 reputation -

I made a few modifications to suit my needs and it worked great when testing on Outlook 2010 and 2016. However, I have been having issues with getting it to work with Outlook 2013. The placeholders are not being replaced the relevant information.

```
On Error Resume Next

Const wdWord = 2
Const wdParagraph = 4
Const wdExtend = 1
Const wdCollapseEnd = 0


strTemplatePath = "\\server\dir\"
strTemplateName = "SignatureTemplate.docx"
strReplyTemplateName = "SignatureTemplateReply.docx"


'----- Connect to AD and get user info -----'
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

strFirstname = objUser.FirstName
strLastName = objUser.givenName
strDepartment = objUser.Department
strInitials = objUser.initials
strName = objUser.FullName
strTitle = objUser.Title
strDescription = objUser.Description
strOffice = objUser.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
strCred = objUser.info
strStreet = objUser.StreetAddress
strLocation = objUser.l
strPostCode = objUser.PostalCode
strPhone = objUser.TelephoneNumber
strMobile = objUser.Mobile
strFax = objUser.FacsimileTelephoneNumber
strEmail = objUser.mail
strWeb = ""

'New Signature
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strTemplatePath & strTemplateName,,True)
Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature
Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries


SearchAndRep "[Name]", strName, objWord
If strTitle = "" Then 
SearchAndRep "[Title]", (objDoc.Bookmarks("title").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete), objDoc
Else SearchAndRep "[Title]", strTitle, objWord
End If
If strDepartment = "" Then 
SearchAndRep "[Department]", (objDoc.Bookmarks("department").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete), objDoc
Else SearchAndRep "[Department]", strDepartment, objWord
End If
SearchAndRep "[Phone]", strPhone, objWord
If strMobile = "" Then 
SearchAndRep "[Mobile]", (objDoc.Bookmarks("mobile").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete), objDoc
Else SearchAndRep "[Mobile]", strMobile, objWord
End If
SearchAndRep "[Fax]", strFax, objWord
SearchAndRep "[OfficePhone]", strOfficePhone, objWord
SearchAndRep "[email]", strEmail, objWord
SearchAndRep "[web]", strWeb, objWord
If strOffice = "" Then 
SearchAndRep "[Office]", (objDoc.Bookmarks("office").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete), objDoc
Else SearchAndRep "[Office]", strOffice, objWord
End If



SearchAndRepHyperlink "[email]", strWeb, objDoc
SearchAndRepHyperlink "[web]", strWeb, objDoc



Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()
objSignatureEntries.Add "Full Signature", objSelection
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Full Signature"

'see note below if a different reply signature is desired
'objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Reply Signature"



objDoc.Saved = TRUE
objDoc.Close
objWord.Quit

'______________________

'Reply Signature
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strTemplatePath & strReplyTemplateName,,True)
Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature
Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

SearchAndRep "[Name]", strName, objWord
If strTitle = "" Then 
SearchAndRep "[Title]", (objDoc.Bookmarks("title").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete), objDoc
Else SearchAndRep "[Title]", strTitle, objWord
End If
If strDepartment = "" Then 
SearchAndRep "[Department]", (objDoc.Bookmarks("department").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete), objDoc
Else SearchAndRep "[Department]", strDepartment, objWord
End If
SearchAndRep "[Phone]", strPhone, objWord
If strMobile = "" Then 
SearchAndRep "[Mobile]", (objDoc.Bookmarks("mobile").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete), objDoc
Else SearchAndRep "[Mobile]", strMobile, objWord
End If
SearchAndRep "[Fax]", strFax, objWord
SearchAndRep "[OfficePhone]", strOfficePhone, objWord
SearchAndRep "[email]", strEmail, objWord
SearchAndRep "[web]", strWeb, objWord
If strOffice = "" Then 
SearchAndRep "[Office]", (objDoc.Bookmarks("office").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete), objDoc
Else SearchAndRep "[Office]", strOffice, objWord
End If


SearchAndRepHyperlink "[email]", strWeb, objDoc
SearchAndRepHyperlink "[web]", strWeb, objDoc



Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()
objSignatureEntries.Add "Reply Signature", objSelection
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Reply Signature"

objDoc.Saved = TRUE
objDoc.Close
objWord.Quit





'----- Subrouting to search and replace template text placeholders -----
Sub SearchAndRep(searchTerm, replaceTerm, WordApp)
    WordApp.Selection.GoTo 1
    With WordApp.Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Text = searchTerm
        .Execute ,,,,,,,,,replaceTerm
    End With
End Sub


'----- Subrouting to search and replace template hyperlink placeholders -----
'         Note this can be picky...if it does not work re-create hyperlink in the template
Sub SearchAndRepHyperlink(searchLink, replaceLink, WordDoc)
    Set colHyperlinks = WordDoc.Hyperlinks
    For Each objHyperlink in colHyperlinks
        If objHyperlink.Address = searchLink Then                                
            objHyperlink.Address = replaceLink
            End If
    Next
End Sub

'WScript.Echo "Signature set"
```

I found this post - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/67184929-d7da-4fba-875b-0e1371f46f2f/vbscript-for-outlook-signature-not-work-with-office-2013?forum=worddev where the answer suggested that the Selection.GoTo was not set correctly. I followed his suggestion but this would not resolve the issue.

The rest of the code seems to work on 2013, the Word template is used and copied into Outlook and set as a signature but the placeholders are not replaced with the active directory information. So the signature (for Outlook 2013) ends up being set as:

[Name]

[Title]

[OfficePhone]

[Mobile]

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out

```
On Error Resume Next
```

tells me that the error is caused by the

```
.Selection.GoTo
```

in the SearchAndRep subroutine.

Suggested by previous comment (now deleted)